# Homeomorphism between the pullback space of a map and the disjoint union of two unit intervals.

Tags: general-topology

Given a path $\beta: I\to \mathbb{RP}^1; t\mapsto p(e^{2\pi i t})$, where $p: S^n\to \mathbb{RP}^1$ is the canonical projection I want to show that the pullback space
$$
\beta^* S^1=\{(t,y)\in I\times S^1: \beta(t)=p(y)\in \mathbb{RP}^1\}
$$
is homeomorphic to $I\sqcup I$.

I propose a function 
$$
\theta: \beta^* S^1\to I\sqcup I
$$
$$
(t, e^{2\pi i t})\mapsto (t,0)
$$
$$
(t, -e^{2\pi i t})\mapsto (t,1)
$$
Now, this function is clearly a well-defined bijection. I have a trouble proving that it is a homeomorphism.

I want to show that $\theta$ is continuous. Suppose that $U\subset I\sqcup I$ is open, then we have 
$$
U=U_0\sqcup U_1
$$
with $U_0, U_1\subset I$ both open, then
\begin{align}
\theta^{-1}(U)&=\theta^{-1}(U_0\sqcup U_1)\\
&=\theta^{-1}(U_0 \times \{0\})\cup \theta^{-1}(U_1\times\{1\})\\
&=\{(t, e^{2\pi i t}): t\in U_0\}\cup \{(t, -e^{2\pi i t}): t\in U_1\}
\end{align}
Now consider $\{(t, e^{2\pi i t}): t\in U_0\}=V_1\times V_2$, where $V_1=U_0$ and $V_2=\{e^{2\pi i t}: t\in U_0\}$, $V_1$ is open by assumption, but how can I show that $V_2$ is open as well?

Comment: Since we know that open subsets of $I$ are finite unions of open intervals, we can write $U_0=\bigcup_{i=0}^n (x_i, x_{i+1})$, then we can consider $\{e^{2\pi i t}: t\in (x_i, x_{i+1})\}$ and show that this is an open subset of $S^1$?

Comment: It is easier if you look at $\theta^{-1}\colon I \sqcup I \to \beta^\ast S^1$. That is easily seen to be continuous, it is bijective, and the spaces are compact (quasicompact and Hausdorff).